# How to install and run gdal_retile?

Tags: gdal, osgeo4w

I want to use `gdal_retile`. I have gdal installed after installing it from OSGeo4W by my `bin` folder is missing `gdal_retile`. How can I install it? I am working on a Windows machine. Is it expected not to be part of GDAL from OSGeo4W?

Edit: I can see my question has been closed due to duplication.
What I am confused about is how I am suppose to install and use gdal_retile. I found an OLD installation from OSGeo4W which include bat files so I can run it as a command line tool. But that does not seem to be the case anymore? gdal_retile itself is a python script? But then I must run it using python not a command line tool? I am completely stumped in what direction I should go to get it running. If I want to use gdal_retile I assume it is not enough to install just gdal?

You can install GDAL in numerous ways
https://gdal.org/download.html
Using the OSGeo4W installer
Or binaries from https://www.gisinternals.com/release.php

I am not a computer scientist and there are too many options for me to understand the differences between them and the requirements to get going. I can post a new question if that make more sense.

Comment: Take care to install also gdal-python. Open the OSGeo4W shell window. Doesn't `command `o-help`  gdal_retile as a supported shell command?

Comment: Hmm ok. I installed a new GSGeo4W "instance". Went straight to Advanced Install and selected GDAL (3.1.4-3) under Commandline util and gdal-python (3.1.4-2) "The GDAL/OGR Python Bindings and Scripts. However there are no *.py files at all in my C:/OSGeo4W64_2 folder where I installed it. The o-help command does not list gdal_retile

Comment: I have 26 python scripts in that directory. I have also used OSGeo4W for installation. I suppose that you have also python-core/python3-core because the installer  tries to take care of installing the required dependencies as well.

Comment: Please do not post a new question. If you believe this one is not a duplicate then it needs to be edited to convince the community that it is not so that they will vote to re-open it. Simply re-asking it a third time will most likely result in an additional duplicates and downvotes.